# Adding tags to files in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

I want to use VSCode as both a code editor and idea journal. And to apply a system like [Zettelkasten](https://writingcooperative.com/zettelkasten-how-one-german-scholar-was-so-freakishly-productive-997e4e0ca125), I would really like to see tags in the file itself, but I can't find any way to add them.

E.g. a note like

```
The dog walked to the park with a bone in his mouth
```

Could be labelled with #dog #walking #park

Comment: [Foam](https://foambubble.github.io/foam/) is based on VSCode and has this feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trying to use a tool for things that it hasn't been designed for leads to a frustrating experience.

VSCode is a great code editor but it isn't a diary or an idea journal, even if you write in Markdown. I believe that you should keep these things separate because there are certain tools for this purpose. Please have a look at [Obsidian](https://obsidian.md), [Foam](https://foambubble.github.io/foam/), and [Geeks Diary](https://github.com/seokju-na/geeks-diary).

Comment: Thanks! Ideally I would have one tool for anything that involves text, but maybe that is too general of a requirement for those use cases.

Comment: Just discovered Obsidian with this answer and looks like perfect app for my notemaking with markdown needs, Thanks!

Comment: @Kartoos You won't regret for this choice. I've been using Obsidian as my Zettelkasten for about two years, and I have never though about switching to any other tool. Linking different notes and thoughts is an absolute winner here. New features are released pretty often, and you can customize Obsidian visually and using plugins wherever you want to make it truly yours. And it's not an advertisement.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for VSCode : [GitHub - chriswheeldon/vscode-ctags: A CTags extension for VSCode](https://github.com/chriswheeldon/vscode-ctags) == [CTags Support - Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jaydenlin.ctags-support) which seem to have many limitation.

I practice "notes-taking" this way inside Notepad++ (a 32bits version on win7-10 64bits), with the help of the *excellent* plugin `SourceCookifier`, which is written in C# language, and is implemented on `Exuberant Ctags`.

This plugin has limitations too : it "badly" supports Unicode ( Unicode chars display as "bad" ascii value/combination ex: `é` --> `E9` , but doesn't raise any error : ugly for the Frenchman, but acceptable in comparison to the features it offers !).
Also, it constraints to the use of a 32bits Notepad++ version : I couldn't find any 64bits compiled version of this (old, orphan) plugin, and this is very sad !

This *powerful* plugin brings almost all programming language "basic" features like class, function, variable declaration, "jump to definition" inside code (ctrl+click), and can operate jump links threw a project folder. The Ctags results is displayed in a sidebar UI, as a list of lists.

It also lets the user to add definitions to a language (I added `todo: bla bla bla` to the languages I use), and we can create our own, named, "language" definitions, defined as a collection of regex expression, with one result per line : multi-line regex results are not supported.

- in:`\b(TODO|DONE|FIX|NOTE): +?(.*)$` out:`\1 : \2`
  will show the respective tag with full phrase (truncated by UI width)
- in:`(#\w+)` out:`\1`
  will show the hashtag #tagged
- in:`^def (\w+) *(\([^\)]+\)) *\:.*` out:`\1 \2`
  will show a python function definition, name and signature

One regex produces a list of results : list of lists ...

Good luck !